# Bismuth vs tungsten shielding

Tags: radiation

When shielding 1250-keV $^{60}$Co at a nuclear facility, are there instances in which a shield produced of a mixture of bismuth and silicon can provide higher/equal attenuation than a shield produced of a similar mixture of tungsten and silicon when both shields are of equal weight?

Comment: Any particular reason it would? Sounds like you may have some more information about this you're not putting in the question.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the silicon vs silicone - was that intentional? And, I would assume you want the shielding to be the same dimensions? Does the 'similar mixture' imply equal atomic fractions or equal weight fractions? Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Please note that Co-60 actually does not emit gamma radiation of 1250 keV. It emits gamma radiation of 1332.5 keV and 1173.2 keV.

Comment: @Loong Yep. But it is not uncommon to simple treat the pair as being 2 1250 keV lines for the purposes of BOTE computations. The error made by doing so is generally lower than that associated with other assumptions in such *ad hoc* work.

Answer (score 0):

Bismuth has a higher Z-value, and attenuation increases with increasing Z-value, although the difference in Z is not that large in this case so I doubt it is a very strong effect. Regardless, the attenuation of the two materials add linearly (neglecting build-up), so the best thing to do is to calculate the attenuation coefficient for the actual materials and densities you have in mind using the data here:

http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/tab3.html